# Where can I find documentation of Microsoft Word VBA runtime errors, with number & description?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Where can I find documentation of Microsoft Word VBA runtime errors, with number & description? I cannot find this anywhere, even after searching Google and Microsoft documentation.

I've worked with Microsoft Access VBA, and that list of errors can be found on a variety of websites. However, I cannot find this for Microsoft Word.

I attempted to generate my own list with the following code, but this only produces those for VBA, not the Microsoft Word Object Library.

```
Public Sub GenerateWordErrorList()

    Dim errnum    As Long
    Dim errtxt    As String
    
    For errnum = 1 To 65535
        errtxt = Error(errnum)
        If errtxt <> "Application-defined or object-defined error" Then
            Debug.Print CStr(errnum), Error(errnum)
        End If
        DoEvents 'Prevent application window from going to sleep while looping.
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that I think it is complete (or remotely up to date) [list of VBA errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa264975(v=vs.60)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) but this is one such list on the former MSKB site for VBA 6.0 dated 2006. There might be a more recent one but if there is I don't know where it is hidden.

I think most of the basic error codes are the same across the Office suite but I haven't really used VBA much outside of Excel spreadsheets so can't be sure.

Comment: Also this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/trappable-errors